# How to implement email aliasing for an entire new domain name to all mailboxes at the old

Tags: dns, email, duplicate-content, mx

The business currently uses a cumbersome URL. It's clunky, but senior staffers are attached to it. We've purchased a few sleek new domains, and for the next few years, *sleekdoma.in* will just forward to *cumb.er.so.me*.

Those staffers won't care about new email addresses, and we want to start using email right away in the *firstname@sleekdoma.in* format. But we'll have a public-facing web site with the cumbersome URL.

So the behavior that I want is that an email sent to *stephen@cumb.er.so.me* will be automatically delivered to *stephen@sleekdoma.in*, without having to manually set up that forward.

I've tried to accomplish this with MX records at Dreamhost, and got myself tangled up. I still haven't found our host moving forward, and would be happiest working with a host that offers this as a service. I'm open to any recommendations, whether DIY or $.

Comment: A couple of things I left unclear:

- The current host isn't Dreamhost. I personally own some 'extra' domains that are parked there so I've been playing with MX records there.

- for email, I want a full domain alias - any mail sent to address A will be handles as mail to address B (including auto-forwards and black holes there).

- I'll actually want three domains aliased to the 'main' email domain.

Comment: If you are using cPanel, then this offers a "Domain Forwarder" option, which seems to do what you are asking?

Comment: Dreamhost supports the feature.  They call it "email mirroring."  I have it set up for some of my domains.

Answer (score 1):

How this is done depends very much on your email hosting provider. Creating an MX record is only the first step as an MX record effectively defines the email server to use for all incoming emails to your domain.

You mention that you don't want to define this manually but unfortunately there is no real effective way to handle this automatically without some complex things being done. I have had to do this once a long time ago and was lucky that the emails where the same across domains (ie: name@domain1.com, name@domain2.com, etc) so that the user block of the email address was the same across all domains. In order to do this automatically I defined a catch all email address in cPanel for each of the unused domains and set that catch all to pipe emails into a PHP script which sent a new email to the correct mailbox using the user block, the from address as a reply to address, etc. This by far is not the best way to do this but was good enough as a short term measure while manually setting email forwarders.

Many emails servers allow you to define email aliases to that the same user has multiple emails defines for themselves for inbound email handling (I have done this mainly with MS Exchange) but once again it needed to be manually done.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamhost supports the feature you want.   Dreamhost calls it "email domain mirroring".   It is in the control panel under "Mail" -> "Custom MX".

After you have added the domain to dreamhost, you can have it mirror your other domain.   That means that all the mail will be delivered to the same mailboxes at the other domain.

I have it set up for one of my domains to mirror my main domain name:

[image: screenshot]